I was born in America, but my dad is from Turkey and my mom is from Romania. Turkey is partly in Asia. Am I genetically part Asian and European?
My parents are first-hand immigrants from Turkey and Romania. Romania is fully in Europe but Turkey is partly in Asia. Am I able to consider myself Asian partly and European partly? Because some of my friends have first hand immigrant parents from China and they’re considered Asian. So what am I?

How do you identify yourself? In the US, that's usually the question.

The scientific position seems to be race doesn't really exist, society just makes it up. Migration of ancient humans involves ongoing research. It makes sense to give different answers in different situations, so tell us more about why you are asking.

Up voting because I don't think it should be closed yet.

Do you think that the genes of people suddenly change as you cross the Bosphorus?  The boundary between Europe and Asia is arbitrary.  Not everyone agrees on where it is or even if Europe and Asia are distinct continents.  Certainly, your genes won't care which side of the river you were born.


Am I able to consider myself Asian partly and European partly?

Yes.
A Eurasian is a person who has one European and one Asian parent or whose family comes from both Europe and Asia.

Turkish people are not "asians" by any measure other than geography. When it comes to ethnicity/genealogy they're balkan and/or middle-eastern.

@littleadv how do you figure?  Their ancestors migrated to Anatolia from modern-day Kazakhstan; they are most closely related to the people of Azerbaijan and Turkmenistan.  More anciently, the origins of the Turkic peoples are thought to lie farther east still.  Definitely neither middle eastern nor Balkan.

Well, by that argument Hungarians and Fins are also Asians and all of us are actually Africans. This is not a question of anthropology though, but rather social identity.

You have asked different questions in the subject and body of your question.

While it is possible to map the genetic profile of a person to so-called racial origin, race is not the same as region. The analysis of your genetic profile would allow a rough estimate of percentages of origin, but the outcome will never be 100% or 0% that. And never exactly 50% of this and 50% of that.
Ethnic Turkish people might have partial Greek or Balkan roots, from Ottoman times, and ethnic Romanian people might have partial Hungarian, or Romani, or Ukrainian roots. Some people find it interesting to pay a genetic analysis service to get a percentage breakdown, others do not want to know or hesitate to give their personal data to such a company.
As far as genetics and demographics go, Turkey is usually not counted as Asia, even if it is geographically mostly Asian. It may or may not be counted as Middle Eastern or West Asian.
The US government asks for ethnicity in their census form and it considered adding a Middle Eastern and North African category. This was bogged down in a political quagmire, because the assignment of ethnic origin by oneself and by others can have social and political consequences.

So my guess is that you should self-report as "White" on US census forms, unless you have ancestors from the Central Asian Turkic peoples in your family tree you're especially proud of.

You can say Turkey not counted as Asia, but the question is about genetics, so if the OP is a Turk, it may be on the the Central Asia region, or in any case more on Asian pert (Turkmenistan hints something, and also all languages of the region). Else.. it depends: Venetian origin? Greek? Ottoman? People/population is very different then geography.

If you were born in Istanbul, your mum could have gone to a hospital on the left or right side of the Bosporus. That won’t change you genetically from European to Asian or vice versa
